# maintain scrollback on ajax modal pop up extender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following site structure. This is a .net 3.5.

Master Page -> Content Page -> Modal Pop up extender -> User control -> Panel -> Update Panel -> div

The div is where all the form elements are. Now, when I click a checkbox or any button that results a postback, the usercontrol starts from the top. It does not maintain the scrollback. I ran across a post about implementing the script below but this doesn't help me any. Is there a fix for this?

Below is the script I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xPos, yPos;
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    xPos = $get('div').scrollLeft;
    yPos = $get('div').scrollTop;
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $get('div').scrollLeft = xPos;
    $get('div').scrollTop = yPos;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the pageLoad section in Javascript, ModalPopupExtenders have a "add_shown" function that can be used for scroll position.

```
function pageLoad() {
var popup = $find('<%=MODALPOPUPEXTENDER.ClientID%>');
popup.add_shown(SetScrollPositionFunction);
}
```

In your case the SetScrollPositionFunction would be EndRequestHandler.